# Binding a list of summary data to a data.frame creates an unknown column in R

Tags: r, summarize, tapply

I have a large df (+100k rows, see snapshot of data below) that I'm trying to summarize (min, mean, median, max, etc.) a variable (salinity) in a table by group (species) using tapply, but if I use the whole dataset (which contains a few NA's, but not in every group) instead of a random subset, tapply adds in an extra column in the table it creates called "NA.s" and it has a value for every group. I'm not sure what this column is or how it's created. Using a subset of randomly chosen rows from the df instead doesn't recreate this issue, so I'm not sure how to reproduce my data here...

I load my data:
[image]

then I run this code:

```
sum_stats <- tapply(df$salinity, df$species, summary)
```

Which seems to create a list of doubles (no NULLs) that look like this:
[image]

Clicking one of them yeilds this, all good:

```
> sum_stats[["Albula vulpes"]]
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  15.49   15.49   15.49   15.49   15.49   15.49
```

Then creating a dataframe creates the issue somehow?

```
sum_data_table<-data.frame(do.call("rbind", sum_stats))

# Not sure what this is either

Warning message:
In rbind(`Achirus lineatus` = c(Min. = 6.11, `1st Qu.` = 20.97,  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

New unknown column circled in red:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you add in the argument to ignore NAs? `tapply(df$salinity, df$species, summary, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: NA.s column still there :(

Comment: Can you provide some of your data? You can just do `dput(head(df))` to provide a few rows.

Comment: There's something about running the code on a random subset number of rows that makes that column not appear. I use this mini_data <- df[sample(nrow(df), 100), ]

Comment: > dput(head(df))
structure(list(species = c("Hippolyte pleuracanthus", "Hippolyte pleuracanthus", 
"Hippolyte pleuracanthus", "Hippolyte pleuracanthus", "Hippolyte pleuracanthus", 
"Hippolyte pleuracanthus"), salinity = c(37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: There are 154 species and an associated salinity value (can be any random number for these purposes).

Comment: I just realized it's the same number as a the 'min' value, for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen because some of the species will not have `NAs` while others will. `summary` will not have the `NA` column if there are none missing and `rbind` doesn’t know how to handle a differing number of columns. You’re seeing the first element repeated (the min) when there are none missing. For species that have some missing, you'll see the count of `NA`

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- expand.grid(letters, letters, letters)
x <- paste0(x$Var1, x$Var2, x$Var3)[1:150]
df <- data.frame(
  species = rep(x, 100),
  salinity = rnorm(15000)
)
df$salinity[df$salinity < -2.2] <- NA 

sum_stats <- tapply(df$salinity, df$species, summary)

sum_data_table<-data.frame(do.call("rbind", sum_stats))
#> Warning in rbind(aaa = structure(c(Min. = -1.7072100148514, `1st Qu.` =
#> -0.755344253350053, : number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector
#> length (arg 4)
```

Removing the missing will work:

```r
sum_stats <- with(df[!is.na(df$salinity) ,] , tapply(salinity, species, summary))

sum_data_table<-data.frame(do.call("rbind", sum_stats))
```

Or you could try using `bind_rows` from `dplyr` instead if you would like a summary of the missingness as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
sum_data_table<-data.frame(do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, sum_stats))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!